# Error deploying war-file to tomcat 9 on Rapidclipse X

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, vaadin

I'm having initial Problems with starting a minimal application created in RapidClipseX on tomcat9 Server, using Java11 (Azul Zulu OpenJdk) on Windows 10 Version 20H2.

I installed RapidClipseX 10.3,  unpacked a tomcat 9 zip file to a directory "tomcat9", installed Azul Zulu OpenJdk 11 and then started the RapidClipseX IDE. First, setup the tomcat9 as local Server for RapidClipseX. Than created a demo project using the new AppLayout Template. After the IDE created here files i clicked on "Build Web App (.war)" in order to build. This went well without any errors. Then i clicked on "Start Servlet" and after selecting the tomcat9 server and adding the app to the list it started.
After a view seconds, in the Console Window the following Errormessage with a lot of other Exceptions came up:

**Failed to determine project directory for dev mode. Directory 'C:\Program Files\XDEV Software\RapidClipse X' does not look like a Maven or Gradle project. Ensure that you have run the prepare-frontend Maven goal, which generates 'flow-build-info.json', prior to deploying your application**

It finished with a final:
**java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/crudtest]]**

And then it stoped working and exited the tomcat server.

I'm aware about the buildprocess for vaadin in general and have already setup project for vaading with maven and spring boot. As far as i can see it was not runing his npm build step. And looking in the generated pom.xml i could not find any signs of using one of the vaadin plugins for this.

I would asume that the RapidClipseX IDE is running out of the box if the enviroment is already capable of building with maven, vaading on Java 11 and has a working installation of tomcat 9. But it doesn't. So could someone please tell me whats wrong here ?

Beste Thx to all answers,
Ralf

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin in development mode needs to find the location of the application's own sources in order to manage client-side dependencies such as the Vaadin web components. The main way of finding this for `.war` deployments is that the `prepare-frontend` goal in `vaadin-maven-plugin` will find the location and store it in a file named `flow-build-info.json` that it puts in a location that is supposed to end up in the generated `.war` file.

I'm not familiar with exactly how RapidClipse X integrates with Maven and with Tomcat, but I suspect your problems are somehow caused by something in that area. The first thing you could do to investigate is to check that `prepare-frontend` has been run at all. You can do this by checking whether there is a `target/classes/META-INF/VAADIN/config/flow-build-info.json` file (and that it contains a couple of entries referring to the absolute location of your application sources). It is possible that RapidClipse X doesn't automatically run `prepare-frontend` and in that case, you would need to do it manually every time the project build has been cleaned.

If the file is present inside the `target` directory, then the next problem might be that it's for some reason not included in the `.war` file that is deployed to Tomcat. You could try to locate the build `.war` file (it might also be in the form of an "exploded war" which is just a directory in the file system with the same contents) and check whether it also contains the same file in the location `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/VAADIN/config/flow-build-info.json`. If the file is missing from there, then one possibility is that RapidClipse X is cleaning the `target` directory before creating a .war, or alternatively that it builds the `.war` from some other location rather than based on the contents of the `target` directory.

I'm afraid I don't have any definite answers for your problem, but only some vague clues about what direction you might need to look into :(. I hope my pointers can still be to at least some assistance.